# Unfolding a sum and making it match hypotheses

Tags: coq

I've unfolded everything except the times 6, but I'm having trouble getting rid of the extra "+1" which is preventing me from rewriting

1 subgoal
n : nat
IHn : 6 * sum_n2 n = n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1)
Sn : S n = n + 1
______________________________________(1/1)
6 * S (n + n * (n + 1) + sum_n2 n) = (n + 1) * (n + 1 + 1) * (2 * (n + 1) + 1)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a tutorial exercise, so this depends a bit on which lemmas you have. Coq has a search function to help you find lemmas.

Below is an example on how you would solve this using standard library lemmas - which might not work for you, e.g. early SF chapters have their own nat definitions and lemmas. But the Search function should show you equivalent lemmas you have.

```
Require Import PeanoNat.

Axiom sum_n2: nat->nat.

Example E1 : forall (n : nat) (IHn : 6 * sum_n2 n = n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1)),
  6 * S (n + n * (n + 1) + sum_n2 n) = (n + 1) * (n + 1 + 1) * (2 * (n + 1) + 1).
Proof.
  intros.
  Search (S _) (_ + 1).
  rewrite <- (Nat.add_1_r (n + n * (n + 1) + sum_n2 n)).
  Search (_ * (_ + _)).
  rewrite (Nat.mul_add_distr_l 6).
  rewrite (Nat.mul_add_distr_l 6).
  rewrite IHn.

  (* You should do this manually as well - just a preview on how one does this after going through the exercises *)
  Require Import Lia.
  lia.
```

This also shows that you can give arguments to lemmas to better control where they are applied.

If you use Coq later, you will just use the lia tactic (for Linear Integer Arithmetic) which can also discharge your goal right away (without the above rewrites). But you should practice and do it manual.

You might want to have a look at the Search function in the manual (https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:cmd.Search).